# How can i use login_url in inline_keyboard Telegram bot php

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have

```
$inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Text","login_url"=>array("url" => "https://example.com"));
$inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1]];
$keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
$replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);

$tg->send2($id, 'Test', $replyMarkup);
```

Function send2 look as

```
public function send2($id, $message, $reply) {   
$data = array(
    'chat_id'      => $id,
    'text'     => $message,
    'reply_markup'     => $reply,
    'parse_mode' => 'html',
);
       
$out = $this->request('sendMessage', $data);
    
return $out;
}
```

If i use 'url' instead 'login_url' it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, it was needed specify parameter DOMAIN in botfather setting

Comment: The question is not clear in the first place. So this is an answer to a question that won't provide any users with insight and should be removed IMO